# Digital piracy of difficult to acquire products

Tags: halacha, technology, gezel-stealing, modern-times, contemporary-halacha

The following discusses copying an item that is being sold by its creator (https://torah.org/learning/honesty-class64/)

> Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ztl said that it’s not permitted to copy any item that is being sold by the creator of that item. Every time you copy it, you’re taking away sales from him. Anybody who downloads it, copies it, or does something else is really just turning someone else’s money into ashes. And that’s really the bottom line. It’s taking something from someone else.

How does this apply to items that one would be likely to buy from a third party in used condition?

What if the creator still sells the product himself, but it is unlikely that one will purchase it directly from him (such as an uncommon book, a foreign film, etc.)? What if the creator no longer sells the product but still holds the rights to it? What if the creator no longer holds the rights?

Comment: This does not answer your question. But I have found that asking the creator for permission often generates a positive response.

Comment: What does you mean by "the creator no longer holds the rights"? Does someone else hold the rights? Why should it matter who holds the rights, as long as they're being held by someone?

Comment: Couldn't the excuse of "creator still sells the product but unlikely to buy from him" open up to any form of piracy?

Comment: magicker72, I'm talking about something that became public-domain where one chooses to download it instead of allowing a third party the opportunity to sell it to him. It seems obvious that there should be no issue here, but I added this question for completness.

Comment: mbloch, you're right. I meant to say,  "If piracy didn't exist, would it be reasonable for one to buy the product?" In a world without piracy, a would-be pirate would be willing to buy an album sold in a local store but not one from overseas.

Comment: @treenuts15 (You need an @ sign before a username in order for the system to let them know you replied.) If it's obvious what the answer is, maybe write something like `If the work is public domain, it seems clear that there's no issue, but in these other cases: ...`.

Comment: Here is a link for at least a partial answer   https://dinonline.org/2019/11/05/using-a-copy-righted-cd/      https://dinonline.org/2017/02/23/can-i-make-a-copy-of-a-cd-belonging-to-someone-else/

Comment: @magicker72 Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Chatzkel Thank you. It's an interesting answer and can be seen practically as there are times when the copyright holder decides to sell a product again after it has been discontinued. But going by this answer, it seems that one would not even be able to buy/sell a used version of the product without the copyright holder's permission.

Comment: @treenuts15 Buying and selling a used version is perhaps somewhat easier, since the person selling the used product in theory will no longer be able to use it (assuming they did not make themselves an illegal copy). In that case, since they have a right to continue using it, they are selling you that right in their place. You are taking their place and purchasing the remaining use left.

Comment: @Chatzkel Ah, okay. Thank you.